# Issue with abi.decode on output from reverted functions

Tags: abi, bytes

I am struggling to figure out the `abi.decode` function when using it to decode the `bytes` coming as output from a reverted low level call to another contract. The way I am using it is by calling the `CheckContract()` function on **contract A**:

```
function CheckContract() public {
    require (!isContract(msg.sender),"No contracts allowed");}
```

from these two functions on **contract B**:

```
function checkWithDecode() public returns (bool, string memory) {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = CheckerAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("CheckContract()"));
    string memory reply = abi.decode(data, (string));
    return (success, reply);
}

function checkWithoutDecode() public returns (bool, bytes memory) {
    (bool success, bytes memory reply) = CheckerAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("CheckContract()"));
    return (success, reply);
}
```

As expected, `CheckContract` reverts on both of the cases and the boolean is `false`. When called from `checkWithoutDecode` the transaction is successful and the output is:

```
{
    "0": "bool: false",
    "1": "bytes: 0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000144e6f20636f6e74726163747320616c6c6f776564000000000000000000000000"
}
```

However, when I attempt to run the decode method on the bytes I receive, using checkWithDecode, the whole transaction fails reverting just at `abi.decode`. Can anyone explain what is wrong with it? How should I decode that output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76653/how-to-decode-error-response-from-contact answer your question?

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry I could not find it myself.